# Data fields are undefined in ASP.Net Core MVC using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

So, I have an issue with my Javascript code. I am using cascading dropdowns, one is for the car brand and another one for the car model. According to logic, when I choose one of the brands from the dropdown (e.g. Toyota or Audi, etc.) the second dropdown should show the models of the selected brand. Generally, I use GetModelsJson method in the controller to join Brand and Model tables and return models as json.

```
public JsonResult GetModelsJson(int p)
        {
            var models = (from x in GetModels() 
                          join y in GetBrands() on x.BrandId equals y.Id 
                          where x.BrandId == p
                          select new
                          {
                              Text = x.Name,
                              Value = x.Id.ToString()
                          }).ToList();
            return new JsonResult(new { data = models });
        }
```

In the view, I want to display the dropdowns using following code:

```
@Html.Label("Brands")
@Html.DropDownList("drpBrand",Model.BrandList,"--Select Brand--", new {@class = "form-control"})
@Html.Label("Models")
@Html.DropDownList("drpModel",Model.ModelList,"--Select Model--", new {@class = "form-control"})
```

The problem starts in the javascript code. Everything works fine until a for loop. For some reason, length of the data variable and other fields like text and value are undefined.

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#drpBrand').change(function(){
            var id = $('#drpBrand').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Admin/Vehicle/GetModelsJson',
                data: {p : id},
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "Json",
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#drpModel').empty();
                    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                        $('#drpModel').append("<option value ='" + data[i].value + "'>" + data[i].text + "</option>");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

As a result, the second dropdown for models becomes empty.
[Picture of the web site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxD5d.png)

As you can see from this picture, the second dropdown is empty, although according to console data has its fields like "A5", "A4", "A6".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the picture you uploaded the object from the server has a "data" field which contains the array so edit your code like this:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#drpBrand').change(function(){
            var id = $('#drpBrand').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Admin/Vehicle/GetModelsJson',
                data: {p : id},
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "Json",
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#drpModel').empty();
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++){
                        $('#drpModel').append("<option value ='" + data.data[i].value + "'>" + data.data[i].text + "</option>");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So please click on the check mark beside the answer to mark my answer as the accepted one!